# .NET Garbage collector many static variables

Tags: c#, static, garbage-collection, immutability

In a recent project I found a lot of public static variables that are hold by static classes. Some of them are strings but others are instances of a class named "Member". Totally, I have around 17151 such static instances.

Questions:
1)   What static instances are considered GC roots ? all of them or only Member instances?. I would guess that strings will be ignored as beying GC roots since string is an immutable type and does not hold references to other types.

2) What would be your advice? To make "Member" class a struct (it is very light, it only has 3-4 fields of type int or bool) or maybe create lazy instances of Member? (declare static properties that make instances of Member only when needed) or other advice... I would apreciate any ideea

Since i made Member as beying immutable and also Member does not hold instances to other objects, is there any possibility to instruct GC from stopping considering these instances as beyind GC roots?

Thank you!

Comment: When Member doesn't hold any outgoing references it doesn't matter if it is a root or not.

Comment: While this certainly is a big smell, 17k small immutable objects/structures is not going to be the showstopper. Don't fix what isn't broken.

Comment: All static variables of a reference type are roots.  Whether the class is immutable plays no role.  One special case for strings, the string object could have started as an interned string when it was a literal in the source code.  They are not roots.  All rather irrelevant, GC is not your problem.  Fixing a program with thousands of public static variables generally requires a rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

> What static instances are considered GC roots ? all of them or only
>   Member instances?.

All static members are considered GC roots.

> I would guess that strings will be ignored as beying GC roots since
>   string is an immutable type and does not hold references to other
>   types.

That is incorrect. a static string declared on a type will be as much of a root as the next static member of a different type.

> What would be your advice?

My advise would be to first see if all these instances are actually causing you memory pressure. If they are, then I would re-think why you need all those static instances in the first place? Do they all need to live for the entire life-time of the process? Can they be cached? Should they really be static members at all? There are many questions you can ask yourself in order to improve.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the ideea is that these Member instances hold a property "Name" and some 2 booleans that are not so important. the "Name" property is the name of a class property that is used in binding with a UI layer. It was done like that for beying able to obfuscate the entire code. When creating a Member instance, the Name property is grabbed using an API that uses Expression tree parsing so if we change the property name, the expression tree also is updated.

Comment: Why does these member instances have to be static ? Could you use the Observer pattern for this ?

Comment: The easyest way would be to put them on non static references around non static classes and create instances of classes that holds these Member buckets when needed. But it is a HUGE amount of work, around 2 weeks of coding / man. It is worth it?

Comment: @GeorgeLica If it is or isn't worth it isn't for us to decide, it will probably be up to your team lead/project manager. What we can say is that these properties don't seem like they need to be static. It sounds more appropriate for them to be instance members inside a class instance.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov Yep, you are so damn right, the simplest thing to do is to move them as instance members inside instance classes. Also I saw that many of them are generated using a T4 template so it will be somehow easyest than I suspected first.